# Primary decomposition of power of a prime.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring with unit. Suppose $P$ is a prime ideal that is not maximal. How can we go about finding a normal (reduced) primary decomposition of the power of $P$, say a normal decomposition for $P^2$ or $P^3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just recently looking into symbolic powers and primary decompositions, and I remember looking at [this script](http://people.reed.edu/~iswanson/primdec.pdf). It didn't really help *me* with my question, but I think that section 8 might be of perfect use to you. You might find more texts by Swanson on the topic, she has done some very nice work in that area.

Comment: I had looked up that article, but still i dont have a good feeling on how to get a primary decomposition of a power of a prime in a specific example say. But thanks.

Comment: @messi This is because there is no clever answer to your question. What Swanson does is purely theoretical and somehow at an asymptotic level.

Comment: @YACP, Yes, you are right. But I wish there was something nice and clever one could say, something very explicit.